# What to use as a knee high wall sill

Tags: shower, sill

I removed the sill that was on top of the knee wall between my shower and bath tub. It seems to be made from some carbonate/plastic. I cannot find anything similar anywhere. I dont even know what they call it.

[image]

What can I use for this and where can I get them..? I really dont want to tile and I'm not wanting to use granite.

Comment: It's probably [Corian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corian).

Answer (score 1):

There are many PVC trim and moulding options out there that would be perfect for this. PVC is now engineered to look like wood or stone, but it is non-porous so it will never warp due to moisture. Google "PVC trim" or "PVC moulding" to shop for some near you.

Comment: I looked at this, but the PVC is really lightweight. What was on there was not PVC.